# Sprite sizing for my game

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, platformer, game-maker

I have recently started a new project with my SO (Significant other)and she is doing the art for my game (Pixel art) now i have always gone with 32x32, 64x64 and so on (Using 16x scale) but she thinks we should only have world objects tiled at that scale i.e the floors and walls etc, but the character and crafted items, weapons etc as whatever other scale, as it wont affect it. Am i correct in thinking this could lead to collision issues, scaling issues etc if we used, say a 50x16 character scale?
I know this may be opinion based (Although im not sure) i just want to know if it will affect things like collision and other mechanic's if the sprites don't all follow the same size scale.

Comment: Could you describe more in depth what kind of issues you think will rise?

Comment: I think that by having the character size not to the scale, it will cause issues with placing objects, objects warping within the player etc. Not sure if im right but just looking for guidance

Comment: The best way to find out if your method will have problems is to try a small test. Put one 50x16 character (just use temp art so you can do it immediately) on a tiled background and observe what problems you encounter. Then describe those problems here and we should be able to help you solve them. It's much easier to fix a problem that's been demonstrated than a hazy possibility on the horizon. Generally though, the only concerns would be graphical (eg. rippling artifacts if you scale sprites by fractional amounts) — your gameplay logic can use its own sizes & hitboxes so it's unaffected.

Comment: Ok so i just tried a 32x32 floor tile, with a 50x40 box as the player, it works fine *Cant believe i didn't think about trying it like this before* ill answer and close this, thanks for the advice. If i get problems with image tearing or any other graphics problems ill post a new question.

Comment: "What size to use" is basically a subjective question. "Will it cause collision problems" is wholly dependant on information you haven't provided concerning how collision works.

Comment: Yeah, ive used a "Pixel Perfect" Collision system, and i have tested my fear with multiple sized sprites and so far its ok, i was trying to avoid creating detailed sprites as it takes her a few hours but the testing was worth it.

Answer (score 2):

so i tested this by using 32x32 floor tile, with a 50x40 box as the player and no problem persists, so thank you to everyone who commented and helped.

Comment: I hope this can be somewhat useful for anyone else having this issue.